# Invariance of eigenvalues of a $0,\pm1 $ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix, signed-graphs

Suppose that $G$ is a signed graph (a graph in which each edge has a positive of negative sign)

Define Adjacency matrix of $G$ as before except that we have $+1$ for positive edges and $-1$

Prove that the eigen values of Adjacency matrix will not change if you multiply some rows and the corresponding columns by $-1$

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know anything about the eigenvectors or eigenvalues of signed graph?  Given that you say "as before," I assume this is copied and pasted from some homework?

Comment: @Aaron Hi. It asked by a friend yesterday and I tried to prove it via induction but it did not work.

Comment: Out of curiosity, in your definition of adjacency matrix, is the diagonal set to 0? (otherwise, multiplying a row by -1 will change the trace, and hence the eigenvalues).

Comment: @Aaron Yes of course

Comment: I'm still not sure how to solve it, but here is a simplifying observation: because eigenvalues are preserved by conjugation, and multiplying some rows by -1 and then multiplying the corresponding columns by -1 is the same as conjugating by a certain diagonal matrix, you can reduce the problem to only considering the action on rows or only considering the action on columns, instead of both at once.

Comment: @Leila I see that you have created ([tag:signed-graph]) tag. It might be useful to create also [tag-wiki or at least tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/signed-graph/info). It might help other users to use the tag correctly. (This is probably not a problem here, since the tag name seems to be descriptive enough.) Another reason is that the tags used on only one question are [automatically deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-pruning/info) after certain time [unless they have tag-wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks. Done!

Comment: Is matrix $\left(\begin{matrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$ an adjacency matrix?  It has eigen values of $\pm1$.  But matrix $\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$ has eigenvalues of $\pm i$.

Comment: @Guangliang I've edit the question Thanks to your comment. "and the corresponding columns"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there are $n$ vertices, and let $J\subset \{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ be the indices of the rows/columns we are going to multiply by $-1$.  Let $E_J$ be the diagonal matrix such that $e_{ii}=-1$ if $i\in J$, $e_{ii}=1$ if $i\not\in J$, and $e_ij=0$ if $i\neq j$.  Then multiplying the rows and columns in $J$ by $-1$ is the same as conjugating by $E_J$.  Since conjugation preserves eigenvalues, we are done.